# inequality involving eigendecomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be an Hermitian matrix. This means the eigenvalues $\lambda_{i}, i = 1, ..., n$ are real and the eigenvectors $v_i, i = 1 ... n$ are orthogonal on each other. We assume that alle eigenvalues are simple and we assume the eigenvalues are in increasing order (so $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2< ...< \lambda_n$), we define $V := [v_1 ... v_n]$ and $\Lambda = diag(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)$ and we note $V_m = [v_1 ... v_m]$ and $\Lambda_m = diag(\lambda_1, ..., \lambda$. This means we can write $A = V \Lambda V^*$
In the paper I'm reading they state the following:
$$\min_{u \in span{V_m}^\bot, \left \| u \right  \| = 1} u^* A u \geq \min_{u \in span{V_m}^\bot, \left \| u \right  \| = 1  }u^* \left( V_m \Lambda_m V_m^* + \lambda_{m+1} (I - V_m V_m^*)\right) u$$ 
I don't know how to use the fact that $u \in span{V_m}^\bot$.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm probably not going to be able to solve it anyway, but what does $spanV^{\bot}$ mean?  Seems to me like $spanV$ is the whole space.

Comment: You are right. It needed to be $span V_m ^\bot$ so I adapt my question. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: If $u\in\text{span}V_{m}^{\perp}$, then shouldn't the first term on the RHS be zero and the second term be just $\lambda_{m+1}$?

Comment: Yeah, the right hand side should just be $\lambda_{m+1}$ as you say, and the LHS is also equal to $\lambda_{m+1}$ in this case, I believe.

Comment: I think the LHS is bigger than $\lambda_{m+1}$, see my answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, my misread; I thought the inequalities on the lambdas went $\lambda_1 > \ldots > \lambda_n$.  Agree with your solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you agree that the RHS is $\lambda_{m+1}$, since the first term is zero and the second term is $\lambda_{m+1}$ (since $I-V_{m}V_{m}^{\top}$ is projection onto $V_{m}^{\perp}$ and $u\in\text{span}V_{m}^{\perp}$). Also assume that $u=\Sigma_{i=m+1}^{n}\alpha_{i}v_{i}$. For the LHS:

[image]

[image]

Sorry, the very last equality should read "=RHS"

Comment: It looks correct. Thank you for the clear response